# Does catching SIGINT in NodeJS prevent default behaviour of Ctrl + C?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, sigint

My nodejs application running on Windows prints ^C and returns the cmd prompt when I press Ctrl + C. But when I use the following SIGINT handler in my code:

```
process.on('SIGINT', (code) => {
console.log("Process exited due to Ctrl + C with code: " + code);
```

});

the statement in console.log() is printed but the process doesn't exit. The cmd prompt is not returned. Pressing Ctrl + C multiple times prints the same statement again and again but cmd prompt does not return. I then have to kill the process by closing the shell. Does handling SIGINT change the default behaviour of Ctrl + C?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is [in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events).

> 'SIGTERM' and 'SIGINT' have default handlers on non-Windows platforms
>   that reset the  terminal mode before exiting with code 128 + signal
>   number. If one of these signals has  a listener installed, its default
>   behavior will be removed (Node.js will no longer exit).

If you want it to exit still, use `process.exit(0)`.